# Xamarin Android binding project and Android support libraries

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

When creating a binding project for a java library that requires the [Android Support Library](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html), how should the reference be added?  Should the Xamarin Support Libraries be used or should the suport lib jar file be included in the project with a ReferenceJar build type?

Answer (score 0):

I've done it by including the appropriate Xamarin Support Library via Nuget. (You might be able to do it by including the reference jar but I'm not sure)